# Como enviar dados em uma sub-pagina BootstrapDialog?

Tags: jquery, bootstrap

Pessoal no exemplo abaixo mostro um formulário dentro de o Dialog, esse formulário por sua vez precisa receber uns parâmetros:

```
BootstrapDialog.show({
        message: function(dialog) {
            var $message = $('<div></div>');
            var pageToLoad = dialog.getData('pageToLoad');
            $message.load(pageToLoad);

            return $message;
        },
        data: {
            'pageToLoad': 'remote.php'
        }
    });
```

Como enviar parâmetros por método POST para a pagina remote.php?

Tentei adicionar data ao array data, mas sem sucesso

Não posso usar GET tem que ser POST

Comment: Você quer postar dados da modal ou fazer o submit do form parent? Sua pergunta me deixou um tanto confuso.

Comment: Veja que na janela modal eu abro o conteudo da pádina remote.php, ao abrir a pagina remote.php preciso receber uns parametros nela, esses parametros tem que ser por metodo post, como ela é carregada via "div".load não consigo enviar esses paremetros, eu testei via get, mas ele não aceita espaço no envio, não sei porque.